# Admin event hook when flex object is saved

Tags: grav

In Grav admin, there is an event hook called `onAdminSave`, which is triggered when you save a page. Is there a similar hook for flex objects, that allows manipulation of flex objects before they are written to the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `grep -roHE --include=*.php "fireEvent\('[^']+'"` inside folder */user/plugins/flex-objects* you will get the following named events:

```
classes/FlexFormFactory.php: fireEvent('onBeforeFlexFormInitialize'
classes/Table/DataTable.php: fireEvent('onTwigSiteVariables'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onFlexTask'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onFlexAction'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onFlexAfterDelete'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onAdminAfterSaveAs'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onAdminCreatePageFrontmatter'
classes/Admin/AdminController.php: fireEvent('onFlexAfterSave'
classes/Controllers/ObjectController.php: fireEvent('gitsync'
classes/Controllers/MediaController.php: fireEvent('onAdminAfterAddMedia'
classes/Controllers/MediaController.php: fireEvent('onAdminAfterDelMedia'
flex-objects.php: fireEvent('onFlexInit'
flex-objects.php: fireEvent('onBeforeFlexFormInitialize'
```

You also might want to take a look at this similar question on Grav's own forum: [Admin Event Hook for Flex Object](https://discourse.getgrav.org/t/admin-event-hook-for-flex-object/18672)